# How can I match the look of my Bootstrap site for a subdomain Wordpress blog?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a personal website (i.e JosephRomo.com) that I made using the Bootstrap framework. I was managing a static html blog which you can see on (josephromo.com/blog.html) but this has started to become really tedious to manage. As a result, I've decided to install Wordpress (josephromo.com/blog , w/o .html) so that I can manage a blog more easily and efficiently. However, being that Wordpress is written in PHP, I am having a hard time figuring out how I can create a theme for Wordpress that looks just like the rest of my main site.

Basically, the biggest thing for me is to keep a consistent navbar aesthetic on the Wordpress site, as it is on my main site, with my JS, active link behaviors and all. Not just the look of the navigation bar but the functionality should be identical. Ideally, by "theme" I mean that the colors for links, and fonts that I have set up through CSS on the main Bootstrap site can be appleid to the Wordpress blog as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a custom theme for your wordpress blog based on any design. I would suggest to google "create a wordpress theme" and you will find tons of tutorials on the subject. or just go to [tutsplus](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-wordpress-theme-in-60-seconds--cms-24315) and read their guide to develop your custom wordpress theme from scratch. I have noticed that you have avada theme installed on http://josephromo.com/blog/ which is like the most robust wordpress theme ever. you can customize it to make any design. Why not watch their [video tutorials](https://avada.theme-fusion.com/advanced-admin-panel/video-tutorials/)? You will find it super easy to match the design of your main site and blog.  My last suggestion would be that you hire a wordpress developer to do it for.